# How to handle manual memory management when reassigning a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-leaks

Say I do something like this:

```
int* arr = new int[30];
int* newArr = new int[30];
arr[15] = 5;
newArr[15] = 9;
arr = newArr;
delete[] newArr;
```

The last line will free newArr, thereby also freeing arr. But what happened to the block of memory which contained 5? Is it now a memory leak which can never be accessed again? If so, how should I go about making sure that this memory can never be leaked, while at the same time successfully reassigning the original array?

Comment: _"thereby also freeing arr"_ Huh??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ arr and newArr point to the same thing, so am I wrong in saying that I free both of them with `delete[] newArr`?

Comment: Freeing both of the same thing? What does that mean?

Comment: The memory that was allocated in 1st place is lost.

Comment: They point to different locations.

Comment: Strictly speaking `delete[] newArr;` doesn't free `newArr` (let alone `arr`). It only frees the memory **pointed to** by both `arr` and `newArr` (because they point to the same location). You actually leaked memory as soon as you called `arr = newArr;`. How do you avoid leaking memory? ***Don't reassign pointers with properly cleaning up as needed.*** (Better yet avoid `new` and rather use modern C++ techniques.)

Comment: @CraigYoung: `new` has its uses - if only as implementation of `std::unique_ptr` et al! :) `new[]`, however, is really quite a useless language feature.

Comment: "How to handle manual memory management when reassigning a pointer?" With sweat and blood and countless all-nighters.  That's exactly the reason why not-so-manual memory management was invented.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I didn't say "never" use `new` or even claim that it didn't have uses. I just advised to avoid it in favour of modern c++ techniques. (_Somewhat as you demonstrated in your own answer._ ;) ) So I really fail to see the point of you comment?

Comment: @CraigYoung: My point was that the OP does not `new` but `new[]`, which I consider a feature different enough to treat it separately. To me, `new[]` is actually a case of "never use". Or at least a much stronger "avoid" than `new`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int* arr = new int[30];
> int* newArr = new int[30];
> arr[15] = 5;
> newArr[15] = 9;
> arr = newArr;
> delete[] newArr;
> ```
>
> The last line will free newArr, thereby also freeing arr.

Not quite. `newArr`and `arr` are just names which point to blocks of memory. You do not really "free newArr", you free the memory block it currently points to. Which in that moment happens to be the same block which `arr` currently points to.

> But what happened to the block of memory which contained 5?

It is still marked as used, but nothing in your program will ever be able to point to it again. The only pointer you ever had to it was `arr`, but you then assigned `arr` to something else.

> Is it now a memory leak which can never be accessed again?

Exactly.

> If so, how should I go about making sure that this memory can never
>   be leaked, while at the same time successfully reassigning the
>   original array?

Forget all this dynamic array nonsense and use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<int> arr(30);
std::vector<int> newArr(30);
arr[15] = 5;
newArr[15] = 9;
arr = newArr;
```

Comment: "Forget all this dynamic array nonsense and use `std::vector`" Funny you mention this, because I actually ran into this problem while trying to implement a vector class on my own in C++ for practice, and it defeats the purpose to use a std::vector in your own implementation of a vector. The pointer was used because the underlying array in a vector implementation needs to be resized at some point, but I'm not quite sure how to do that without creating memory leaks...

Comment: @CoffeeMaker: `std::vector`'s implementation does not use `new[]` but placement new (which allows it to reserve memory in advance in a smart way). Not that this helps you much here. You must learn how to implement your assignment operator such that the old memory is freed. Hint: free memory in your destructor, look up the "Rule Of Three" and implement assignment with the "Copy & Swap" idiom.

Answer (score 0):

> The last line will free `newArr`, thereby also freeing `arr`

With `free(p)`, you are not freeing `p` but the memory block **pointed by `p`**.

---

With `arr = newArr`, you've essentially "lost trace" of the dynamically allocated memory block that was originally pointed by `arr`, which means that you can no longer deallocate it at a later point in the execution of your program, hence a memory leak becomes inevitable.